# Getting current branch in IBM ODM Decision Center

Tags: ibm-odm

Is it possible with the Decision Center API to get the name of the current branch? I would like to implement a dynamic domain plugin that updates domains by querying from a database. But I want to be able to specify local, test, stage and prod database connection details. Because we are sharing a single decision center instance for test, stage and prod, the project branch seems like the best option for targeting the database. Is it possible to determine what branch I am in when I trigger the DomainValueProvider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get determine the current branch by calling the *getWorkingBaseline* method on *IlrSession*:

```
private String determineBranch(IlrSession ilrSession) {
    IlrBaseline currentBranch = ilrSession.getWorkingBaseline();
    String branch = currentBranch.getName();
    log.info( "currentBranch is " + branch);
    return branch;
}
```

If you are implementing an *IlrDefaultSessionController*, *IlrSession* will be provided if you override the *setSession(IlrSession session)* method. From elsewhere, you can get the session from *ManagerBean*:

```
protected IlrSession getIlrSession() {
    ManagerBean bean = ManagerBean.getInstance();
    return bean.getSession();
}
```

Good luck!